# ¿Cćmo puedo mostrar un valor en consola que se actualiza constantemente sin saltar de línea en c++?

Tags: c++, manejo-de-memoria, stdout

¿Cómo puedo mostrar un valor en consola que se actualiza constantemente sin saltar de línea?

En este caso son las coordenadas de un juego, y quiero que me muestre el valor de estas, pero sin que salte de línea al estar actualizándolas.

Comment: ¿En que entorno estas?  Si es linux puedes usar [watch](https://linux.die.net/man/1/watch)

Comment: @masterguru se me olvido poner que era en c++, crees que ahi me puedas ayudar?

Comment: No se c++, lo siento.  En linux podrias dejarlo ejecutando con `watch` pero dudo que sea lo que quieres.. imagino que con la etiqueta que has puesto de stdout lo quieres controlar todo el tiempo con c++ en lugar de llamar al programa con watch cada x segundos.

Comment: Ya intentaste borrando constantemente la consola ?, de esa manera tus coordenadas se mostraran en tiempo real y sin cambiar de posición en la consola. las coords es lo único que necesitas imprimir en consola ?, estas usando funciones de lectura de memoria ?

Comment: ¿Has probado a emplear comandos VT100?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que necesitas es '**\r**', es decir, un retorno de carro que coloque el cursor al principio de la linea y asi en vez de saltar de linea la proxima vez se sobreescribirá.

Fuente:
[How do I rewrite a line of text in a console project? c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350254/how-do-i-rewrite-a-line-of-text-in-a-console-project-c)